# Recursion with two increments

Tags: java, arrays, performance, algorithm, recursion

I am trying to create a recursion function that allows me to "simulate" a double for loop. Something similar to

Iterative:

```
  for(int i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
       for(int x = i; x < list.length; x++) { 
            //handle logic here
       }
  }
```

Recursive:

```
 public int solve(int start_index, int end_index) {

      if(start_index >= array.length) { return 0; }
      if(end_index >= array.length - 1) { solve(start_index + 1, 0); return 0; }

      return solve(start_index, end_index + 1);
 }
```

But it doesn't seem to return results similar to I think it should. Can any one help me out? Appreciate it!

Comment: Well what results are you seeing, and what do you expect to see? (Your code would be a lot clearer if you used more line breaks, by the way... especially for multi-statement blocks.)

Comment: Your second code block appears to be missing a `}`. Is that your actual code?

Comment: @Kevin updated. i think i kinda missed it out a little.

Comment: @JonSkeet I just started on recursion, I tried printing out the start and end index but it always seem to have an extra case which I cannot eliminate that causes index out of bounds error.. I have also tried using the debug tools to step in and realized that even after printing it will carry out a few more sequences before it ends, which I don't really understand too.

Comment: My actual problem is to attempt to count all the possible additions in an array with recursion.

Comment: @toffee.beanns please see the working example in my answer.

Comment: @JonSkeet guru sir, I would appreciate a comment to my answer if you have time.

Answer (score 0):

Lets say your operation is a sum of an integer array. That's the iterative version:

```
for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++)
  for (int x = i; x < array.length; x++)
    sum1 += array[x];
```

The recursive version will be something like:

```
public int solve(int x, int i, int end)
{
  if(i == end)
    return array[x];
  else if(x == end)
    return array[x] + solve(i + 1, i + 1, end);
  else
    return array[x] + solve(x + 1, i, end);
}
```

We would call it with `sum2 = solve(0, 0, array.length-1);`

The semantics of the variables `i` and `x` is the same on both the versions for better understanding.

In the end `sum1` will be the same as `sum2`.

Answer (score 0):

This should work (Note I am simulating similar behavior):

```
public class temp {

        // This will be the method to simulate the double for loop you had 
        // listed in your question.
        static void iterate(int index, int sub_index, int end_index) {

                if (index < end_index){
                        if (sub_index < end_index ){
                                System.out.println(index + " " + sub_index );
                                iterate(index, sub_index + 1  , end_index);

                        }else {
                                iterate(index + 1, index+1 , end_index) ;
                        }
                }
        }



        public static void main(String[] args){
                // Simulate the usual double for loop
                System.out.println("Double for loop");
                for (int i = 0 ; i < 3 ; i++){
                        for (int j = i ; j < 3 ; j++){
                                System.out.println(i + " " +  j);
                        }
                }

                // Simulate the double for loop through recursion
                System.out.println("Double for loop through recursion");
                iterate(0,0,3);

        }

}
```

and the output will be:

```
Double for loop
0 0
0 1
0 2
1 1
1 2
2 2
Double for loop through recursion
0 0
0 1
0 2
1 1
1 2
2 2
```